# One to one relation anomaly

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I am a bit confused by the behaviour of LINQ To SQL (just for clarity I do not mean EntiyFramework or LINQ To Entity but old LINQ To SQL).

I have a relation between *Entity* and *Resources*. Entities are subject of my code (for example people) and resources are things used by entities (for example documents).
To map the relation I use a cross join table EntityResource and the Resource table.

When I need to refresh the resources associated to an *Entity* I delete all record form the cross join table (ResourceEntity) for a given *Entity*, then scan the *Entity* and search to see if for each *Resource* in the Entity if there is already an item in Resource table (resources may be shared among many entities).
If the *Resource* exist I just recreate the relation, otherwise first I create the *Resource* and then the relation.
Finally I delete all *Resource* that have no *Entity* association through the EntityResource cross join table.

My problem arises in the phase of association rebuilding, when I scan an *Entity* to re-associate existing *Resource*

```
foreach (var candidareResource in candidateResources) //set of resources for a given entity
{
    tbl_res_ResourcesEntity relation = new tbl_res_ResourcesEntity() //cross join table rebuild from a specific entity_id (already deleted here i just rebuild it)
    {
        ENTITY_ID       = entity.Id,
        ENTITY_TYPE_ID  = (int)entity.EType,
        ID_LANG         = candidareResource.ID_LANG,
        //navigation to Resource (1,1) relation is NULL by now
    };

    repository.Create(relation);
    //create is almost context.tbl_res_ResourcesEntities.InsertOnSubmit(relation);

    context.SubmitChanges();

    repository.AttachResource(relation, candidareResource);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

AttachResource basically check that the resource I try to create does not exist, if it exists create only association, otherwise create the resource and then the association, here the code:

```
public virtual tbl_res_ResourcesEntity AttachResource (tbl_res_ResourcesEntity objToUpdate, tbl_res_Resource resourceToAttach)
{
    base.Update(objToUpdate);

    if ( objToUpdate.ID <= 0)
        throw new ExtendedArgumentException("resourceToAttach", "No valid resource");

    var dbObjectToUpdate = this.Datacontext.tbl_res_ResourcesEntities.FirstOrDefault(res => res.ID == objToUpdate.ID);
    var dbResource = this.Datacontext.tbl_res_Resources.FirstOrDefault(res => res.RESOURCE_KEY == resourceToAttach.RESOURCE_KEY && res.RESOURCE_TYPE == resourceToAttach.RESOURCE_TYPE);

    
    if (dbResource == null) //always false in my testing scenario
    {
        dbResource = resourceToAttach;
        dbResource.SanifyLinqEntity();
        
        this.Datacontext.tbl_res_Resources.InsertOnSubmit(dbResource);
    }

    dbObjectToUpdate.Resource = dbResource;

    return dbObjectToUpdate;
}
```

In my scenario the Resources always exist so ignore the `(dbResource == null)`

Here is how the ORM show entity relation :

[image: ORM UI]

[image: One to One association]

The issue arise when the same resource, is used many times by an *Entity*. This may happen if I would attach a document (Eg : a pdf file) twice. It's a bit strange, but document are attached in a language, so if entity request it in a specific language I have localization. But sometimes you don't have a localized document (eg : a PDF in English meant to be viewed also for the French language) and so the same resource end up to be attached twice. This is not an issue because document is stored only once, the "link" is doubled

So I get my PDF doubled

**Resource**

| ID | ID_LANG | RES_KEY | RES_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | en | document.pdf | pdf |

**ResourceEntity** (cross join table)

| ID | ENTITY_ID | ENTITY_TYPE | RESOURCE_ID | RESOURCE_TYPE | ID_LANG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Person | 1 | pdf | en |
| 2 | 1 | Person | 1 | pdf | fr |

**Entity**

| ID | NAME | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | Person |

Problem is, if I try to attach the same Resource more than once (to the same entity), I got an error:

> An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a tbl_res_Resource and a tbl_res_ResourcesEntity. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (tbl_res_ResourcesEntity.RESOURCE_ID, tbl_res_ResourcesEntity.RESOURCE_TYPE_ID) cannot be set to null.

Not clear why I am seeing that behaviour.

Comment: I think i get the mistake. it's a really really silly one. I have my 1-1 relation, but due to L2SQL way of represent it i have to make the child entity (resource) the parent and go back to cross join. But in that direction is not a 1-1 relation anymore, it become a 1-many.. Changing cardinality solve the issue (apparently.. i'll test it more)